# Validation always True (blank=False) for CharField but not with DateField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have an `inlineformset_factory` containing a field. When this field is a CharField (`blank=False`) and I run `is_valid()` on the formset, `True` is always returned even though the CharField is left blank. When I replace the CharField with a DateField (`default=timezone.now(), blank=False`), `is_valid()` will return `True` only when the field is filled as expected. Why is the CharField always returning `True` when running `is_valid()` on the formset but the DateField does not? Note that I want the CharField to behave like the DateField.

Interestingly enough, the formset behaves as expected when both the CharField and DateField are present.

Code below is shown with title and date but I have tried with *only* title and *only* date as described above. Any help is appreciated. This is driving me up the wall!

models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)    

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now(), blank=False)
```

forms.py

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('author', 'description')    

class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title', 'date')    

BookFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(
    Author,
    Book,
    form=BookForm,
    fields=('title', 'date'),
    extra=1,
    can_delete=False,
    can_order=False
)
```

views.py

```
class CreateAuthorView(CreateView):
    template_name = "author_create.html"
    model = Author
    form_class = AuthorForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateAuthorView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            form = self.get_form(self.form_class)
            context["book"] = BookFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=form.instance)
        else:
            context["book"] = BookFormSet()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        book = context["book"]

        print(form.data.get("author"))
        print("book.is_valid()", book.is_valid()) # ***This always prints True when only CharField is part of Book model***

        return redirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("author_list")
```

author_create.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        {{ form }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ book.management_form }}
        {% for book_form in book %}
            <div>
                {{ book_form }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit Author</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Note that title need a max_length keyword and dont need blank=False because its the default value. Normally, its works as your mind. You can check it out with printing field.widget.is_required through adding __init__() in BookForm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with formsets, completely empty forms are not validated unless the minimum/maximum number is set in the formset definition itself.